# OpenCV C++ using Visual Studio 2015 error

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.1

I'm a beginner to opencv, and I've been trying out some basic things using the library. I've added all the dependencies in VS, so generally the image processing related codes work. However, I am getting the following error on the console for one video-related program:

> warning: Error opening file
>   (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:578) Press any
>   key to continue.

My code is as follows:

```
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
namedWindow("Video", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(argv[1]);

Mat frame;
for (;;) {
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty()) break;
    imshow("Video", frame);
    if (waitKey(33) >= 0) break;
}
return 0;
}
```

I downloaded ffmpeg, and added it my Path environment variable as well, it did not work.
I've searched quite extensively online for this, but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check video path and ffmpeg supported format?

Comment: Yes, path is correct, and it is an avi file.

Comment: I doubt you forgot to include videoio header or copy ffmpeg dll to your compiled binary.